# Como verificar se uma composição poética é um tautograma?

Tags: python

O usuário digita uma frase e eu tenho que verificar se todas as letras iniciais de cada palavra são iguais. Até agora meu código está assim:

```
frase = str(input()).split
if frase == frase[0]:
    print("tautograma")
else:
    print("Não é um tautograma")
```

Exemplo de um Tautograma:

> Dentro desta devassa desilusão, Deixaste dias dourados de desalentos,
> Decorados de déspota dor.

Como posso resolver?

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70) e [Que erro cometi ao fazer minha pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8388/70).

Answer (score 2):

Fiz de uma maneira mais simples pra ficar fácil de você entender:

Colocando a frase com todas as letras minusculas para evitar erro de comparação:

```
frase = 'Dentro desta devassa desilusão, Deixaste dias dourados de desalentos, Decorados de déspota dor.'.lower()
```

Dividindo a string em fatias para formar uma lista de palavras:

```
palavras = frase.split(' ')
```

Caso uma letra diferente da inicial o script para, caso seja igual ele continua rodando e contando as letras iniciais:

**Edit:**
Como sugestão do hkotsubo, removendo o contator fica mais legível e fácil de entender:

```
frase = 'Dentro desta devassa desilusão, Deixaste dias dourados de desalentos, Decorados de déspota dor.'.lower()
palavras = frase.split(' ')

for palavra in palavras:
    if palavra[0] != frase[0]:
        print('A frase não é um Tautograma.')
        break
else:
    print('A frase é um Tautograma.')
```

---

Uma outra maneira mais 'avançada':

```
frase = 'Dentro desta devassa desilusão, Deixaste dias dourados de desalentos, Decorados de déspota dor.'.lower()
palavras = frase.split(' ')
len(palavras) == len([i for i in palavras if i[0] == frase[0]])
```

Retorna True se for um Tautograma e False caso não seja.

Comment: Não precisa desse contador, pode usar um `for`/`else`: https://ideone.com/xhGkap - mas na verdade não precisa nem disso e nem de criar uma lista: https://ideone.com/8P4nvi

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que percebi, a autora da pergunta está tentando implementar um algoritmo que verifique se uma sequência de palavras é ou não um `tautograma`.

Pois bem. Antes de tudo devemos definir o que é [tautograma](https://www.recantodasletras.com.br/teorialiteraria/1068102).

> *Tautograma é uma composição poética em que TODAS as palavras começam com a mesma letra. A beleza do tautograma reside na capacidade do compositor combinar as palavras de modo que produzam um sentido poético.*

Para resolver esta questão podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
poema = input('Composição poética: ').lower().split()

if len({i[0] for i in poema}) == 1:
    print('É tautograma')
else:
    print('Não é tautograma')
```

Observe que neste código é capturado uma composição poética. Em seguida, o bloco **if** verifica se o tamanho do conjunto formado por apenas a letra inicial de cada palavra da composição poética é igual a **1**. Caso positivo, a composição poética é um tautograma. Caso negativo, não é tautograma.

---

Caso preferia, também podemos implementar uma função. Desta forma o código ficaria:

```
def verifica_tautograma(p):
    return len({i[0] for i in p}) == 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    poema = input('Composição poética: ').lower().split()
    resposta = verifica_tautograma(poema)

    print(resposta)
```

Neste código o retorna da função será apenas um valor booleano - **True** ou **False**. Então, caso a composição poética seja um tautograma, o retorno da função será **True**. Caso contrário, o retorno será **False**.